# PHP static site generator

Tags: php, html

I am currently building up a static website with PHP.
What I want to have is the following:
There is one main.php file that includes all the common parts of the page (header, footer, navigation and so on) and a couple of pages like index.php, team.php, contact.php and so on.
I do want to be able to edit the main.php in that way, that is effects all the pages in my project. I do however want to be able to output some specific content for each single page by writing code directly in the specific file (not main.php but e.g. index.php). So I want to assign each page of the project to use main.php as the core template.
My main.php file which looks so far like this is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP Static Site Genarator</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="navigation">
        <?php echo navigation()?>
    </div>

    <div id="pageWrap">
        <header>
            Header
        </header>
        <main id="content">

            <?php echo $templateContent; ?>

        </main>
        <footer>
            Footer
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

and a couple of pages like index.php, contact.php and so on.
All of them look like this:

```
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/essentials/settings.php'; ?>
<h1>
    This is the h1 for the index page
</h1>

<?php require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/essentials/exit.php'); ?>
```

I deliver some settings in my settings.php file and in my exit.php file I have the following code:

```
<?php 

$templateContent = ob_get_contents(); 

ob_end_clean();

echo $templateContent;
?>
```

I need to somehow bind all the pages to be the part of main.php at the point where I output the $templateContent variable at

What is the right way for me to achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by _"update only the files of pages"_? When? In what way? Do you mean that you want the contents to change without reloading the page? Please edit your question to include more details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I mean that I want to update index.php, but not the main.php and I want all the contents of index.php to be inserted in main.php instead of $templateContent variable

Comment: We don't know anything more about your application than what you've posted. We also don't know you've implemented the above "templates". The question is still lacking information. Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65093974/edit) to include a _detailed_ explanation of what you're trying to do (do it in steps, like when I do this, I want this to happen instead of that but with much more details). It would also help if you included what issue you're trying to solve.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson updated, hope, this makes sense

Comment: Yes, that made it easier to understand. I would actually recommend using some templating engine. There are those that doesn't require you do learn a brand new syntax, but just uses plain PHP, like [Plates](https://platesphp.com/). There you can create layouts (like your main.php) and then just let the other pages say what layout it wants to use. Then the templating engine does the rest.

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck in your process of developing that application?

Comment: @NicoHaase exactly at the point of binding pages to template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would consider using a micro PHP framework like [lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/), [slim](https://www.slimframework.com/), [fat-free-framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) for making even the smallest PHP web application.

That said, below is the solution of the approach you took to solve the problem. I will keep the file structure and file naming similar to yours, even though there is a place for improvement here.

Lets consider the following application structure:

```console
essentials/main.php
essentials/navigation.php
essentials/exit.php
essentials/settings.php
index.php
about.php
contact.php
```

As you can see, I have moved all common files into the `essentials` folder and left all pages in the `root` folder

**essentials/settings.php**

```html
<?php

// start output buffering
ob_start();
```

**essentials/navigation.php**

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">index</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">about us</a></li>
</ul>
```

**main.php**

```html
<?php $templateContent = ob_get_clean(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP Static Site Generator</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="navigation">
        <?php include("navigation.php"); ?>
    </div>

    <div id="pageWrap">
        <header>
            Header
        </header>
        <main id="content">

            <?= $templateContent; ?>

        </main>
        <footer>
            Footer
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>

<?php require_once("exit.php"); ?>
```

**essentials/exit.php**

```html
<?php 

ob_end_flush();
```

The actual pages structure **index.php, about.php and contact.php** look similar:

**index.php**

```html
<?php require_once("./essentials/settings.php"); ?>

<h1>
    This is the h1 for the index page
</h1>

<?php require_once("./essentials/main.php"); ?>
```

I hope this helps to move your idea forward, but highly encourage you to investigate time and learn a  modern approach for PHP application development. [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) is a great stating point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

Structure

```
index.php
about.php
core\function.php
core\setting.php
templates\header.php
templates\footer.php
templates\menu.php
```

- core\function.php - all function in here
- core\setting.php - all setting in here
- templates* - html page

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once("core\setting.php");
include_once("core\function.php");

/*
* code php for this file in here
*/
$message = 'index data';

include_once("core\header.php");
include_once("core\menu.php");

echo <<<HTML

<div>show content {$message}</div>

HTML;

include_once("core\footer.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are looking for template engine.
There are many out there like [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/intro.html), [Blade](https://github.com/mattstauffer/Torch/tree/master/components/view), [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/)

Or you can write one alone like it is explained in this excellent [post by David Adams](https://codeshack.io/lightweight-template-engine-php/)